# Cannot open any file for writing in Perl on Windows 10 (on one particular machine)

Tags: perl, windows-10

I have the weirdest problem. Consider the following Perl script:

```
system('echo > echo.txt');

open(FILE, '>', "out.txt") or die "Can't open file ($^E)";
print FILE "Hello";
close(FILE);
```

Ignore that it is horribly written or that there are not the appropriate `use strict` or `use warnings`, for the behaviour is the same for any script. Using a recent Strawberry Perl on a recent Windows 10 Pro install on one machine, it does what you expect: it creates two files "echo.txt" and "out.txt". On another machine, with Windows 10 too and the latest version of Strawberry Perl, the script creates "echo.txt" but then the `open` fails with `$^E` set to "Access denied" (actually in Italian, "Accesso negato"). It is true for this and any other script in any directory I tried, invariably.

Of course, I checked the directory permissions: the user logged in has complete permissions inherited from the enclosing directory. I added full control for Everybody and it did not change a thing. I opened a command prompt as Administrator and launched the script there, to no avail. And, again, I tried this in a variety of directories on a couple of different physical disks.

I have uninstalled Strawberry Perl and reinstalled it but, perhaps predictably, no difference. Let me also mention that the failing PC has been installed from scratch only recently (a couple of weeks ago), but no problem whatsoever has been observed so far.

What am I doing wrong?! It must be something really silly, but I do not see it. How can I debug this?

### Update #1

It turns out that everything runs fine in "c:\Users...\Downloads" but not in "c:\Users...\Desktop" nor in its subfolders nor in other directories created by the user that I could try.

Here is what `dir /q` says of these two folders:

```
c:\Users\Flavia>dir /q
 Il volume nell'unità C non ha etichetta.
 Numero di serie del volume: 28CE-96F1

 Directory di c:\Users\Flavia

28.09.2021  14:33    <DIR>          BUILTIN\Administrators .
28.09.2021  14:33    <DIR>          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    ..
[...]
29.09.2021  09:14    <DIR>          DESKTOP-TBFQ31Q\Flavia Desktop
[...]
29.09.2021  09:13    <DIR>          DESKTOP-TBFQ31Q\Flavia Downloads
[...]
               2 File      1’627’775 byte
              24 Directory  401’441’447’936 byte disponibili
```

The owner is the same and is the one running the Perl script (see below). And here is what `icacls` says:

```
c:\Users\Flavia>icacls Desktop
Desktop NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
        BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
        DESKTOP-TBFQ31Q\Flavia:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)

Elaborazione completata per 1 file. Elaborazione non riuscita per 0 file

c:\Users\Flavia>icacls Downloads
Downloads NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
          BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
          DESKTOP-TBFQ31Q\Flavia:(OI)(CI)(F)

Elaborazione completata per 1 file. Elaborazione non riuscita per 0 file
```

Everyone has (F) or Full access. Clearly, the only difference is the (I) on Desktop, which I believe means that it the permissions are inherited from the parent folder. Maybe this is related to the problem (since I cannot observe any other difference) but I cannot see why and how. And, to support the fact that this (I) is irrelevant, I also checked on the PC where the script works everywhere as expected: the output difference of `icacls` between Desktop and Downloads is exactly the same (I) for Desktop--and, yet, there the script works equally fine in both folders.

Here is what the GUI says about the two folders on the failing PC:

[image: Permissions in the GUI]

I used Process Monitor to ascertain that it tries to write the correct files and, for instance, is not accidentally trying somewhere else. Here is the appropriate excerpt from Process Monitor:

[image: Process Monitor entries]

Although this is a test in a subfolder of the Desktop, it is exactly identical to the failure in the Desktop. I checked the two processes which failed (perl.exe) and succeeded (cmd.exe invoked by perl.exe) and they look both healthy (in particular, the owner of the processes is as expected):

[image: Failed perl.exe]
[image: Succeeded cmd.exe]

In Downloads, perl.exe succeeds but I see no difference:

[image: Succeeded perl.exe]

I am **totally clueless**.

### Update #2

Some discussions with people and comments here started to make me think that maybe Windows 10 has some security feature preventing the particular binary perl.exe from writing (if it is true, I have no idea of what I am talking about--and I wish I knew). Anyway, I decided to uninstall Strawberry Perl (already done, see above) and reinstall it but now using the previous version (5.32.0.1 instead of 5.32.1.1). Lo and behold, everything works like a charm. But why?! If you are tempted to think that it is a bug in the release 5.32.1.1 of Strawberry Perl, you may want to consider that on the other machine where everything works it is 5.32.1.1 which is installed. Checked the MSI installer used a couple of months ago there and a couple of days ago here: the very same file down to the last byte. Funny, uh?!

My immediate issue is solved but I still have **not the slightest clue** of what has happened and how I should have properly debugged the problem.

Comment: Hmm...have you ever tried [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)? Might not hurt to give it a shot to see if there are any more details...

Comment: Try using an absolute path instead of a relative.

Comment: @flashbang, I did try but do not know Process Monitor well; after your comment I tried again. The "Detail" in the monitor for the mysteriously failed open is *exactly* the same as on the working PC if I set the file Read-Only beforehand (where, in these conditions, of course, it fails too). So, no use, except that I have confirmed what I expected and looks normal: that the user running the Perl process which is refused the access is the same user who owns the directory (and for which they have Full Contol--besides the fact that I have added Full Control also for Everybody).

Comment: @TLP, I tried the absolute path for the sake of it (and it changed nothing) but from the experiment with Process Monitor I know that the file Perl is trying to open is exactly the one I expect.

Comment: And you are sure that the file that you know exactly which one it is is a file that you have permission to write to?

Comment: What is outcome of `echo "Hello" > echo.txt` from command prompt in same directory?

Comment: @TLP, the file does not exist and I would expect it to be created.

Comment: @PolarBear, the command you suggest works as it should and creates the file. But this is not surprising: even Perl manages to spawn cmd.exe and produce through it echo.txt (in the Process Monitor I could see this and check that cmd.exe is a child process of Perl, apparently running with the same user and rights). It is really the open() from Perl that fails. For that matter, also openL() from Win32::LongPath fails.

Comment: Try creating a new directory and see if it works there. This feels unlikely to be a Perl problem, more likely a file/directory/permissions. "Access denied" is an unusual error. Usually if there is a permission problem, it says "permission denied". Perhaps you are using a hard drive that is access via a network?

Comment: @TLP, I tried to create various other directories, even in different volumes, but the behaviour is perfectly consistent. As for the message, on the faulty PC it is actually in Italian ("Accesso negato"); when I get the script to fail on the good PC by creating the file beforehand and making it read-only, the message is "Access is denied". I agree that it looks a Windows permission problem more than a Perl problem (of course, we all understand that the test script is correct...) but it is odd that only Perl has the issue (even a child of the Perl process manages to write in the directory).

Comment: @Paolo Can you try do exactly the same with a Python script? If it works with Python, we know that it is a problem with perl

Comment: @HåkonHægland, I am sorry but I am not going to embark in installing Python: clearly it is not a Perl language issue (the script works and everyone sees it is correct); if it works for Python and not Perl it only means that the Perl executable misses some rights that the Phyton executable does have, somehow per chance--but this would not tell us much, would it? Thanks for trying to help, though--I appreciate.